# Future catchError function doesn't catch error when its not chained immediately

Tags: dart, asynchronous, future

consider this code:
**EXAMPLE A:**

```
Future<void> fakeCall() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300), () {
    throw MyError('myException');
  });
}

Future<void> fetch() async {
  Future<void> testFuture = fakeCall();

  testFuture.whenComplete(() {
    print('when completed');
  });
  testFuture.catchError((e) {
    print('on error');
  });
  return testFuture;
}

void main() async {
 try{
  await fetch();
  }on MyError catch(e){
     //getting here but one still leaks!!
  }
}
```

when calling `await fetch()` I expect only `catchError` to be called. but the Error somehow leaks, so basically two were thrown...one caught by `catchError` and one is leaked outside as an unhandled error.

but when using it the proposed way (chained one after the other):
**EXAMPLE B:**

```
Future<void> fakeCall() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300), () {
    throw MyError('myException');
  });
}

Future<void> fetch() async {
  Future<void> testFuture = fakeCall().whenComplete(() {
    print('when completed');
  }).catchError((e) {
    print('on error');
  });

  return testFuture;
}

void main() async {
 try{
  await fetch();
  }on MyError catch(e){
     //getting here and nothing leaks!!
  }
}
```

No error leaking occurs.
It just left me very curious,
**can someone explain why writing it in the first way makes the error to leak?**

---

## update

originally I forgot to add try/catch around the fetch function, so
you might think the error leaked for this reason. but notice, the  error still leaks when not chaining the onError properly (first example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is leaked because you are awaiting the result on a `Future` which ends up being completed with an error in:

```
await fetch();
```

It is important to understand that a `Future` object is just a value which gets a value sometimes in the future and this value can either be a value or an error.

The `catchError()` is a way to subscribe some code to be executed if the `Future` gets completed as an error. The method returns a new future with the logic that it gets the origin value in case of the origin future gets completed without any error. But if the origin gets completed with an error, the `catchError()` runs a specified method and returns the value after this execution.

The `catchError()` does not change anything about the origin `Future` and you can therefore call `catchError()` as many times you want.

I should add that I think it is better to use a traditional try...catch (combined with `await`) inside async-marked functions instead of playing with `catchError()` since it makes the code more readable and less confusing:

```
Future<void> fetch() async {
  try {
    await fakeCall();
  } catch (e) {
    print('on error');
  } finally {
    print('when completed');
  }
}

void main() async {
  await fetch();
}
```

Outputs:

```
on error
when completed
```

### Update after question was changed

The problem with "Example B" is that you assume that `whenComplete()` does handle any errors. But if you read the the documentation:

> **The future returned by this call, `f`, will complete the same way as this future** unless an error occurs in the `action` call, or in a Future returned by the `action` call. If the call to `action` does not return a future, its return value is ignored.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-async/Future/whenComplete.html

So the returned `Future` have not changed its behavior so if the origin `Future` completes with an error, the same is happening with the `Future` created from `whenComplete()`. And since you are not attaching any error handling on this `Future`, your program fails.

Comment: Awesome, I was waiting to see your answer on this!!

Comment: I have added try/catch around the fetch method and the error still leaks when not using the chaining properly - see the update on my post...

Comment: @vigdora The error you are seeing in the updated example comes from the future spawned from `whenComplete()` which are not handling the exception. If you add an `onError` on the `Future` spawned from `whenComplete()` you can catch the exception.

Comment: so when not chaining the whenComplete properly, the spawned future returned from whenComplete left unhandled, thus the error leaks?

Comment: @vigdora Added a section to my answer about details for `whenComplete()` behavior.